# CSS margin when element inside has position absolute

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm in a quite annoying situation...
I think it's the best to just show what I've made and tell you what the problem is, instead of explaining everything.

I've been searching for a solution quite a while now, but I can't find it.

If you go to http://jsfiddle.net/bd3Ms/ you see a three boxes with a h1 tag and an image inside. I have clipped the image with CSS(this has to be done this way, can't get around that). I'm trying to center the image in the box, but I can't manage to do that. I think that's because of the absolute positioning of the img element.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
        .photo-div {
            overflow:auto;
            height:250px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        .photo-div-content {
            width:100%;
            margin:0 auto;
        }

        img.clipped {
            position:absolute;
            clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,0px);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="div-1" class="photo-div span4">
                <div class="photo-div-content">
                    <h1>Logitech Mouse</h1>
                    <img class="clipped" src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div id="div-2" class="photo-div span4">
                <div class="photo-div-content">
                    <h1>Logitech Mouse</h1>
                    <img class="clipped" src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="div-3" class="photo-div span4">
                <div class="photo-div-content">
                    <h1>Logitech Mouse</h1>
                    <img class="clipped" src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am using Twitter Bootstrap and the website I'm building is going to be fully responsive, so just adding a margin-left is does not work for me..

I hope I managed to make clear what the problem is.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it with the same technique I use for CSS sprites.

```
.photo-div-content{
    background: 'url('IMG URL') repeat scroll -0px -0px transparent');
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For now I think this is the best way to reach my goal: using CSS to show a part of an image in the middle of a div.

Comment: You should accept your answer if it's what solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

What about not clipping and centering the image?

```
img.clipped {
    background:url(https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bd3Ms/1/

More alternatives here:

- Absolute Center (Vertical & Horizontal) an Image
   http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/
- Creating Thumbnails Using the CSS Clip Property: 
   http://www.seifi.org/css/creating-thumbnails-using-the-css-clip-property.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to centre both the text and the clipped image. See if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/7Lq6B/

The important bit is that I've wrapped the images in a centred div which is the same size as your clipping dimensions.

**CSS**

```
.img-wrap{ /* dimensions should match clipping size */
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div-2" class="photo-div span4">
<div class="photo-div-content">
<h1>Logitech Mouse</h1>
<div class="img-wrap">
<img class="clipped" src="https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As the image is absolutely positioned you have more options to play with. Try this:

```
img.clipped {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    clip:rect(0px,200px,200px,0px);
}
```

It's not pretty code, but it's in the middle of the parent div.